# Merging TypeScript interfaces inside modules

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to merge the Matchers interface from jasmine. 
The interface is declare inside the jasmine namespace.

I have created .d.ts file and added the following:

```
declare namespace jasmine {
    interface Matchers {
        toBeSuccessful(): boolean;
    }
}
```

This works, but if I try to add an import statement to the .d.ts file it doesn't work. The *toBeSuccessful* function is not recognized.

I also tried to add this portion of the code inside my implementation of the function and not inside of the d.ts file, but then, other members of the namespace are not available anymore, for instance in this code:

```
class ToBeSuccessfulMatcher implements jasmine.CustomMatcher {
    compare<T>(actual: Result<T>): jasmine.CustomMatcherResult {
    }
}
```

The interfaces CustomMatcher and CustomMatcherResult are not available anymore.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `import` statement to the declaration file turns that `.d.ts` file into a module, and "moves" all declarations in the file into the scope of that module.

So `namespace jasmine` in your `.d.ts` file is no more in the same scope as the "real" `namespace jasmine` (most likely, that one is in the global scope), so your `interface Matchers` is also in the different scope than real `Matchers`,  and *declarations from different scopes are not merged*.

The solution, when you have `import` or `export` at top level in your `.d.ts` file, is to use explicit `global` scope there:

```
declare global {
    namespace jasmine {
        interface Matchers {
            toBeSuccessful(): boolean;
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, see also "global augmentation" at the very end of [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) document.

Also, when you add `Matchers` interface inside your implementation, again it's in the different scope than the real `Matchers`, and it hides jasmine `Matchers` instead of merging with it.