# import statements in .d.ts file along with declare module does not work

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

---

- **What works =>**

---

I have a `index.d.ts` file in my app root where I have global things declared for example global modules.

So my `index.d.ts` looks like following:

```js
declare module 'moment';
```

and I can import `moment` in any `.ts` file without any error.

---

- **Where problem arises =>**

---

**Now problem arises when I import something in my `index.d.ts` file to make more declarations. Lets say my as follows:**

```js
import { MyService } from './path/to/file';   //line#1

declare module 'moment';

export interface SomeInterface {
 name: string;
 salary: number;
 myService: MyService
}
```

Now any imports in my `.ts` file that were importing `moment` are erroneous and throw `Cannot find module 'moment'.ts(2307)`

As soon as I comment `line#1`, the `moment` imports start working again.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the MyService class exported in the MyService.ts or whereever it is defined?

Comment: yes it is an exported member of `'./path/to/file'`

Comment: This is a problem with mixing ambient module declarations with import statements. You can find more discussion and a potential solution with TS 2.9 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51114250/5416902)

Comment: thanks man. This is exactly what I was facing and seems like this is how typescript is by design and I'm not doing anything wrong here.

Comment: Yeah no problem!