# How using types.d.ts file in React & TypeScript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have React & TypeScript project. 
Here is i have folder structure in some component like:

```
 - ComponentFolder
  - index.tsx
  - types.d.ts
  - ChildComponent
    - index.tsx
```

I know that if i will put my types in **types.d.ts** file which in root of my component directory, I can use these types in childComponents in this directory.

So i tried;

my **types.d.ts** file:

```
export type CommonProps = {
  openItem: string;
  getValue: (e: React.MouseEvent) => void;
};
```

and in child component:

```
import * as React from "react";

const ChildComponent: React.FC<CommonProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.openItem}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChildComponent;
```

But getting error:

```
cannot find CommonProps error.
```

How i know if i have some file d.ts in the directory i can use these types in this directory without import.

where i mistaken?

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `export` keyword.

```
type CommonProps = {
  openItem: string;
  getValue: (e: React.MouseEvent) => void;
};
```

Comment: or import the type from it location

Comment: @felixmosh Not really, the whole target about types.dev.ts is to be able to use interfaces without a need to import it.

Comment: Where can I find documentation about this? My problem is that if I try to import types, it also stops working. Using the import or export keyword breaks auto-type-discovery.

Comment: Found an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51114250/124416