# importing into index.d.ts is breaking my types

Tags: typescript, typescript-declarations

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "target": "es6",                          
    "module": "commonjs",                    
    "declaration": true,                   
    "strict": true,                          
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "@types"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@types/*": ["@types/*"]
    },
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./*", "@types"]
}
```

**@types/index.d.ts**

```js
import { ExecException } from 'child_process';
type error = ExecException | null;

interface Person {
  is: boolean;
  str: string;
}

type doThingX = (is: boolean) => boolean;
```

**example.ts**

```js
const jon: Person = {
  is: 'hello world'
}

const doThing: TdoThing = x => `${x}`;
```

If I comment out the import then the existing types - Person, and doThing are found and work in example.ts
If I keep the reference to the import then it breaks and example.ts cannot find the types for Person of doThing.

> Cannot find name 'Person'.ts(2304)
> Exported variable 'jon' has or is using private name 'Person'.ts(4025)

> Cannot find name 'TdoThing'.ts(2304)
> Exported variable 'doThing' has or is using private name 'TdoThing'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the reason:
Credit: [Import class in definition file (*d.ts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040108/import-class-in-definition-file-d-ts)

My fix:

**index.d.ts**

```js
type error = import('child_process').ExecException | null;

interface Person {
  is: boolean;
  str: string;
}

type TdoThing = (is: boolean) => boolean;
```