# How can I manually map apollo custom scalars to client side types

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

**How can I manually map apollo custom scalars to client side types?**

I wan't to change the type which is associated with a Field Policy. (I am trying to [essentially do this](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/2), i.e. manually add support for a custom scalar type). The value from the server is a `string` but I wan't to convert it to a JS Data (more specifically a `luxon` `DateTime`)

I have a schema like this:

```
export interface SomeType {
  __typename: "SomeType";
  created: GraphQLDateTime;
}
```

I have a field policy like this:

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      SomeType: {
        fields: {
          created: {
            read: (created: string): DateTime => DateTime.fromISO(created)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

I have a `graphqlScalars.d.ts` type file to provide mapping of custom types to JS types:

```
type GraphQLDateTime = string
```

I am unable to switch my type definition file to something like as it causes import issues:

```
type GraphQLDateTime = DateTime
```

The problem is, the field resolver works as expected (i.e. it converts my ISO8601 string into a `luxon` `DateTime`) but the `TS` typing system (because of the `graphqlScalars.d.ts` type definition) expects `created` to be a `string` so `DateTime` typings are not available on it.

This is the typing of the `read` function:

`export declare type FieldReadFunction<TExisting = any, TReadResult = TExisting> = (existing: SafeReadonly<TExisting> | undefined, options: FieldFunctionOptions) => TReadResult | undefined;`

**How can I manually map apollo custom scalars to client side types?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing [this `TS` issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040108/import-class-in-definition-file-d-ts) I was able to manually map my type in the following way using import syntax:

```
type GraphQLDateTime = import('@types/luxon').DateTime
```

Now in my code `created` (that has been converted via a `FieldPolicy` is converted to the correct typing.

Comment: Very useful! Do you know how you can convert all fields of a certain type via `TypePolicies`? Or do you have to add a type policy for all fields that contain your custom scalar type?

Comment: Based on my previous research, I don't think there is a stable / supported way to do that. You need to manually map the custom scalars. The apollo github issue for this is [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/2). There are a few plugins mentioned in there, but they seem a little hacky.