# Typescript: import other types in a type definition file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a type defintion file for one of my modules which has a defintion for a lot of interfaces. I am trying to break down the definition into multiple files for better organization

```
// original file - index.d.ts
declare module 'my-module' {
  interface A { }
  interface B { }
  interface C { }
  export interface D {
    a: A,
    b: B,
    c: C
  }
}
```

// the setup that I am looking for

```
// A.d.ts
export interface A {}

// B.d.ts 
export interface B {}

// index.d.ts
declare module 'my-module' {
  // import A.d.ts here
  // import B.d.ts here
}
```

How do i import `A.d.ts` and `B.d.ts` in `index.d.ts` ?

One of the ways i have seen it working is using a `import()` syntax, where I can do something like:

```
declare module 'my-module' {
   export interface D {
     a: import('../A.d.ts').A
     ...
   }
}
```

I also understand that a regular import on top of the file does not work as it changes the global declaration to a module, but why doesn't a import inside the declare keyword work ?

```
declare module 'my-module' {
  import { A } from '../A.d.ts';
  export interface D {
    a: A
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: did you have a look at this=>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040108/import-class-in-definition-file-d-ts

Comment: I did, which is how I got to understand the import() syntax, but not the fact why regular import can't work

Comment: @gaurav5430 I'm facing the same issue. Have you got a solution?

Comment: no, not yet @HKIT9