# @types/react-table: How to include configured types for users of my package?

Tags: typescript, npm, react-table, definitelytyped

**Context**:
We are developing a UI-component library with React and TypeScript and use `react-table` for our table component. The library is published as an npm package and used in our other projects.

I have configured the types as described in the [documentation of `@types/react-table`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-table) in a file called `react-table-config.d.ts`. Additionally, I have created a new type `CustomColumn`. It is based on the `Column` definition and extends its functionality to support nested string accessors (so that TypeScript can recognize whether `foo.bar` is a valid string accessor for the given table data).

**Goal**:
I would like to provide this improved TypeScript support to our library users. I especially want them to be able to use the `CustomColumn`.

**Problem:**
When I install the library package in another project, I lose access to my configured types for `react-table`. They are not even included in the package.

If possible, I would like to avoid having to publish a separate package for the typings, though I assume this approach would work.

**What I've tried so far:**
I was surprised that this does not work off the bat, because we [successfully extend the Emotion-Theme with a similar mechanism of extending type declarations](https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript#define-a-theme). To make the custom theme available to users of the library, we simply renamed `emotion.d.ts` to `emotion.ts`.

I have tried the same with `react-table-config.d.ts` (=> `react-table-config.ts`) and ran into a lot of TypeScript errors because while the documentation and current TypeScript etiquette recommends the use of `Record<,>`, in the actual type definitions from DefinitelyTyped, they use objects in their generics.

After resolving the resulting Type conflicts, the `react-table-config.d.ts` is now generated by the transpiler and included in the package, but my custom types are still not utilized when I use them in the other project.

Other things I have tried so far:

- Adapting `compilerOptions.typeRoots` in the `tsconfig.json` of the component library
- Adapting `compilerOptions.paths` in the `tsconfig.json` of the "using" library
- Changing the imports in an attempt to make `react-table-config.d.ts` an ambient module, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51114250/15143272)
- using `/// <reference path="../../@types/react-table-config.ts"/>` in the `index.ts` where I (try to) re-export `Cell` and `CustomColumn`.

I would really like to understand why this does not work, especially because the Theme overwrite for Emotion is working. The differences I could point out is that Emotion supports TypeScript off the bat, so there is no separate package for the types.

If there is any specific code that would be of help I will try to provide it (if possible) - but as this is more of a systemic issue I don't want to post code indiscriminately.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, custom types that i defined in my library `react-table.d.ts` is not being recognized by consuming application, due to which build process of the consuming application is failing. One way is to copy paste the same `react-table.d.ts` from the component library to the consuming application `types`, but that defeats the purpose. Please let me know if you are able to solve this isse

Comment: Hey @Jawad, unfortunately I haven't found a solution up until now :(

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating a `custom.d.ts` file in my `types` folder of consuming application. In this file I'm referencing the custom types in my component library

```
/// <reference types="<component-library>/types/react-table" />
```

In my component library `types` folder I have `react-table.d.ts` which contains all the type overrides. Something like

```
/* eslint-disable */
import { UseRowSelectInstanceProps, UseRowSelectRowProps, UseRowSelectState, UseTableColumnOptions } from 'react-table';

declare module 'react-table' {
    export interface ColumnInterface<D extends object = {}> extends UseTableColumnOptions<D> {
        collapse?: boolean;
        centerHeader?: boolean;
    }
    export interface TableInstance<D extends object = {}>
        extends Omit<TableOptions<D>, 'columns' | 'pageCount'>,
            UseTableInstanceProps<D>,
            UseRowSelectInstanceProps<D> {}

    export interface Row<D extends object = {}> extends UseTableRowProps<D>, UseRowSelectRowProps<D> {}

    export interface TableState<D extends object = {}> extends UseRowSelectState<D> {
        hiddenColumns?: Array<IdType<D>> | undefined;
    }
}
```