# How to export an imported interface from ambient module?

Tags: typescript

`SomeClass.ts`:

```
export interface SomeClass {
  print(): void;
}
```

`external-types.d.ts`

```
import { SomeClass } from "./SomeClass";
declare module "printer" {
  // How to export SomeClass from this module?
  // I have several other interfaces spread across
  // files that I want to export from here.
}
```

The solution I am not looking for is, moving the interface into module declaration.
Because I have lot of interfaces across files and I simply want to import and re-export them from the module.

Comment: Have you tried `export { SomeClass } from './SomeClass'`?

Comment: yup. that did not work.

`Import or export declaration in an ambient module declaration cannot reference module through relative module name`

Comment: Can you use [import type expressions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-2-9-rc/#import-types) as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66768386/1426891)?