# Vite can't resolve import .d.ts file

Tags: typescript, vite

I want to import type from type.d.ts file

```
import type { StateDefinition } from '../type'
```

vite cannot find file and throw error
[image]

So I should add extention .d.ts

```
import type { StateDefinition } from '../type.d.ts'
```

but I will get ts error in vscode
[image]

anyone can tell me how to fix it?

Comment: you could refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040108/import-class-in-definition-file-d-ts

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue and figured out the following cause: if you're importing *both* `interface`s and `enum`s in the same statement like:

```
import { SomeType, AnEnum } from '@/types/general'
```

The import will be causing the error above. However, if you replace it to:

```
import type { SomeType } from '@/types/general.d.ts'`
```

Then it will work. Just put any `enum`s you might have somewhere else.